# IIS 7 set up web service on port 8080 with SSL

Tags: ssl, iis-7

I'm trying to set up a web service on port 8080 with SSL on IIS 7.  There is already a website set up on port 80 with SSL.  I've tried a few things like adding a https binding with port 443 and a https binding with port 8080 but that didn't work.  How should this be done?